# No cross/minimize button on AVD emulator

Tags: android, windows, emulation, android-virtual-device

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=25h1i7q&s=8#.VcISK26qpBd

Apparently since I don't have enough rep points, I cannot upload an image, so you can find the image in the link above.

Whenever I try running the virtual emulator, the emulator will start and work properly, but there is no cross/minimize button available, which not only makes it hard to quit the application, but also makes it impossible to move the window around. 
I have tried disabling host GPU but that hasn't helped either.
Any ideas on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Proabably its hidden up there by your titlebar of the curruntly active window ,
 One thing you can try is make it smaller by adjusting the avd size from avd manager in android studio. This happens normally to me in ubuntu

Comment: I've tried making it smaller, but it doesn't help.
Well, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll do that. Thanks.